# Is there a way to read a simple one line asp page using a batch file?

Tags: batch, batch-file, wget

I have a simple asp page in which i write an ip address, and nothing more.

Now i need a batch file to read the contents of this page and pass it to a variable.

I'm not good with batch files but it seems that FOR can read only from local folders and wget needs to be installed in order to read online files.

Is there any way i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wget is portable](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/). [cURL is too](http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?CURL_7.37.0).

You can download these two binaries and use them in your batch script as required. Just make sure the EXE files are located in the same directory as the batch script. Or if you want to access globally, [add their locations to the PATH variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

You can fetch a page using WGET by using the command:

```
WGET http://somewebsite.com/index.asp -O index.asp
```

### UPDATE:

To fetch a web page using Telnet, first run the script as administrator and include this line of code somewhere in the script:

```
dism /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient
```

After that, [use this clever method of sending text to a telnet session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13200564/1768141). Create a file called SendKeys.vbs in the same folder as the batch script and make sure it contains these lines of code:

```
set OBJECT=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'sleep for 50 msec
WScript.sleep 50
'fetch the index.htm page. Replace this with the page you want to fetch
OBJECT.SendKeys "GET /index.htm {ENTER}"
'sleep for 4 secs
WScript.sleep 4000
'terminate telnet session
OBJECT.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

and for the batch script, use this:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM change elegantetchings.com to your web server address
start telnet elegantetchings.com 80
cscript SendKeys.vbs
pause
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work. But it does the job a bit differently than i expected. I'd like to read the content of index.asp and store it to a variable, not to download the index and then read it. Plus i need to run this batch to many Pcs that don't have wget and i'd like not to get in trouble installing it to everyone. What alternatives do i have?

Comment: There is a way to do that. It's not used often. You can use Telnet to grab web page output. It's [explained here](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/279466). However, it does require that you have Telnet enabled on all the computers you are running your script on. You can enable Telnet from "Turn Windows features on or off" under "Programs and Features" in the Control Panel

Comment: Bascially, the commands are: `telnet somewebsite.com 80` and then you type in `GET /index.asp`. Press Enter and you'll see the HTML source code of the entire page in the console

Comment: However, this is a really bad way to do things. I'd recommend you take a look at [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) for Windows automation. You can use AutoIt to do some really cool stuff. Also, their software documentation is extremely detailed and impeccable. You can also compile your AutoIt scripts to self sustained EXE files so you can run your scripts on computers that don't have AutoIt

Comment: Yes, telnet isn't available by default but you can enable it under the "Turn Windows features on or off" option under "Programs and Features" in the Control Panel. You can do this from your batch script (if you run it with administrator privileges) using this command: `dism /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient`

Comment: i missed one of your comments sorry. i'm reading about telnet right now i guess telnet will have enough functionality to do what wget does, right?

Comment: Telnet wasn't designed to do what wget does, so no. Please read my updated answer. That might help.

Comment: oh, you mean that with telnet i'd get the source code istead of just the contents, right?

Comment: No, I meant that Telnet was designed [mostly for remote administration](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/T/Telnet.html) of workstations and not for fetching files from web servers, which is what WGET does.